# How to get the list of the top facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm curious if there's anyway to get a list of all Facebook pages with their associated likes/followers count? I've noticed that there are sites that provide this data (e.g. Top 100 Facebook pages) but I'd like a more comprehensive list.

Comment: No, there is no way to get such a list via API.

Comment: How are these other websites doing it? Is there some other way? @CBroe